# Activity not visible in Recents when app is in background

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-recents

#### Issue description

In one of my apps I am seeing quite odd behaviour: when my app is running in foreground (is top-most one), then I can see its activities in system's Recents. But as soon as I put it into background, the same activity (i.e. `AccountsActivity`) that was listed moments ago is no longer present in Recents. Related portion of my Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:name=".WebnetApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AccountsActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    ...
```

#### Findings

Since this is the only app of mine that misbehaves that way, I checked all styles, and my `WebnetActivity` and `WebnetApplication` to ensure I do not call anything that could influence Recents. There's nothing like this.

Then I started to strip down Manifest file to see if something would change. And as expected, the culprit lurks there, still it's no really clear for me why. At start, `AccountsActivity` entry in Manifest had no `android:excludeFromRecents` entry at all - this resulted in `AccountsActivity` being not visible in Recents at all. When I added `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` then the activity becomes visible in Recents, but only when it was in front. When I moved to back, then it disappeared from Recents. When I remove `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` from `StartActivity` declaration, then `AccountsActivity` become visible in Recents regardless app is in front or in background and I can remove `android:excludeFromRecents` from its entry completely without any problems as well.

#### Question

At the moment I am bending my head trying to understand why it all behaves that way - is it normal (and I do not know something) or it is perhaps rather bug in framework? Anyone faced similar issue and can share experience, ideas or explanation?

Comment: have you tried it in multiple devices? Be sure first before banging your head.

Comment: Good point, yet yes, I tried to repro on many devices and emulators and it happens all the time. It occurs on 2.x and on 4.x. I haven't tried if my "fix" solves this issue for 2.x, but it does for 4.x

Comment: I am preety sure your blunder is android:launchMode="singleTask" along with exculdeFromRecents a singletask will never leave a backstack and excludefromrecents prevents the one that could be on backstack from being there not so sure

Comment: But I kept `android:launchMode="singleTask"` - only removed `excludeFromRecents` from `StartActivity` and all works. That's why I am in WTF mode now.

Comment: What's the entry point for `AccountsActivity`? From what I can see, that's `StartActivity` -> `AccountsActivity`. No?

Comment: @shoerat: why does it matter?

Comment: I am not sure, but `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` of the parent activity can be causing that behaviour. Can you post the intent you are using to launch `AccountsActivity`?

Comment: @shoerat: no flags. Just ordinary `startActivity()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` from main activity.

Quote from [android:excludeFromRecents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude):

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is,
>   when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute
>   determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent
>   apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; set
>   "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

Comment: "That is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task"

Comment: The word "task" is what I managed to not spot in right context. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

Just Remove

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

or set to false will solve your problem.